# Pasar un valor de una función a otra javaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con un select y quiero obtener el valor del option que cambia y pasarlo a la función string con el fin de realizar una consulta asíncrona a la base de datos con Ajax, sin embargo siempre obtengo undefined, siempre he tenido muchos problemas cuando tengo que pasar valores de una función a otra y la verad no se cual es el metodo apropiado para hacerlo.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
<div class="filters bg-light border-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light pr-0 pl-0 pt-4 pb-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-block d-md-none" href="#">Filtros</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler border-0 pr-0 pl-0 text-dark filters_btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filtersToggle" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-bar-down" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM8 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.793l2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708L7.5 12.293V6.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 6z"/>
                  </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="filtersToggle">
        <div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
            <div class="row">
                <%if( all_brands) { %>
                <form action="/product/filters" method="GET" class="w-100 d-flex flex-wrap">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 p-0 pr-0 pr-md-3 mt-md-0">
                        <select class="form-control capitalize" id="brand_filter" name="brand">
                            <option value="no_brand" disabled selected>Seleccione una marca</option>
                                <% for(i=0; i<all_brands.length; i++){ %>
                                    <option value=<%= all_brands[i] %>><%= all_brands[i] %></option>
                                <% } %>    
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-3 pr-0 pr-md-3 p-0 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                        <select class="form-control" id="model_filter" name="model" disabled>
                            <option disabled selected>Seleccione un modelo</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 p-0  pr-0 pr-md-3 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                        <select class="form-control" id="initialPrice_filter" name="initialPrice">
                            <option disabled selected>Precio desde</option>
                            <option>chevrolet</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 p-0  pr-0 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0">
                        <select class="form-control" id="finalPrice_filter" name="finalPrice">
                            <option disabled selected>precio hasta</option>
                            <option>chevrolet</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 pr-0 pr-md-3 col-md-3 mt-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="AutoManual_filter" name="AutoManual" disabled>
                            <option disabled selected>Transmisión</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 pr-0 pr-md-3 col-md-3 mt-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="initialKm_filter" name="initialKm">
                            <option disabled selected>Kilometrage desde</option>
                            <option>chevrolet</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 pr-0 pr-md-3 col-md-3 mt-4">
                        <select class="form-control finalKm" name="finalKm" id="finalKm_filter">
                            <option disabled selected>Kilometrage hasta</option>
                            <option>chevrolet</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 p-0 col-md-3 mt-4">
                        <select class="form-control" name="color" id="filter">
                            <option disabled selected>Color</option>
                            <option>chevrolet</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                </form>
               <% } %>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codigo js

```
  //select
    const brand_filter = document.getElementById("brand_filter");

 const params = {};   
 
    params.car_brand = () => {
        if(brand_filter){
            brand_filter.addEventListener("change", function(){
                return brand_filter.value;
            });
        }
    }
    
    

    
    function string(){
        var x = params.car_brand ()
        console.log(x);
    }
    
    string();
```

Comment: sé más específico con esta pregunta, agradecería si pudieras poner el código HTML

Comment: Hola, si ya  puse el html

Comment: Pon el codigo JS

Comment: El código JS está abajo del HTML

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás tratando de obtener el valor antes de que se modifique.

Prueba con esto

```
const params = {
   card_brand: () => {
      return brand_filter.value;
   }
};

brand_filter.addEventListener("change", () => {
   console.log(params.card_brand());
});

// Los elementos con ID único de HTML se convierten en constantes de javascript
```

Comment: Ahora si funcionaria, esto es correcto.